How to prevent IME (Input Method Editor) to mutate the contenteditable element?
If i use an IME (press Windows key + . on windows to open it), it will mutate the contenteditable="true" element.
I have already tried to:

disabling the events (beforeinput, keydown, compositionstart, compositionupdate, compositionend)

stopping the event propagation


The only solution I see is the new EditContext API, but it is in an experimental state and with its current functionalities, I'm not sure that it can replace the contenteditable.

Have you tried dealing with the consequences instead, to allow users to use the tool they want to to input characters? Preventing system-level features is always spotty at best, if not impossible.

I'm not sure that we are on the same page. Preventing the IME to modify the contenteditable (the DOM) is not really a system-level feature IMO.

preventing win + . from doing what it does would be preventing a system level feature. What i'm saying is you're better off dealing with the consequences of it, because chances are you either can't prevent it, or if you find a way to it'll stop working. In what way is it "mutating" the contenteditable? it certainly doesn't seem to be "mutating" it to me, it just inserts a character.

Sorry I didn't understand what you were trying to say with the "consequences" part before.
I'm currently working on a rich text editor where I have to check every user action (like enter, delete/backspace, character typing, copy-paste) that would modify the content of the contenteditable, even if it's just a simple character insertion.

The input event does get triggered when a character is added via win + ., it should also be triggered with copy paste, enter, delete/backspace, etc

Yes, the beforeinput, input, composition(start|update|end) events are triggers when I use the IME, but none of them able to prevent the string to be inserted into the contenteditable.
